# Unable to locate package default-jdk on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, java, jdk

Actually i was trying to install Java(for Hadoop) on Ubuntu 16.04. But whenever i try to run sudo apt-get update i always get the error of:

```
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-i386_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-all_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_i18n_Translation-en (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_restricted_binary-i386_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_restricted_binary-all_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_restricted_i18n_Translation-en (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_universe_binary-amd64_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_universe_binary-i386_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_universe_binary-all_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_universe_i18n_Translation-en (1)

E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_multiverse_binary-all_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-i386_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_binary-all_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_i18n_Translation-en (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_restricted_binary-i386_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_restricted_binary-all_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_restricted_i18n_Translation-en (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_universe_binary-amd64_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_universe_binary-i386_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_universe_binary-all_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_universe_i18n_Translation-en (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_multiverse_binary-all_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_main_binary-amd64_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_main_binary-i386_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_main_binary-all_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_main_i18n_Translation-en (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_restricted_binary-i386_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_restricted_binary-all_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_restricted_i18n_Translation-en (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_universe_binary-amd64_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_universe_binary-i386_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_universe_binary-all_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_universe_i18n_Translation-en (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_multiverse_binary-all_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_main_binary-amd64_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_main_binary-i386_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_main_binary-all_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_main_i18n_Translation-en (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_restricted_binary-i386_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_restricted_binary-all_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_restricted_i18n_Translation-en (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_universe_binary-amd64_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_universe_binary-i386_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_universe_binary-all_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_universe_i18n_Translation-en (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_multiverse_binary-all_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en (1)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: The package cache file is corrupted
```

and after that whenever i run the command of:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

i always get an error of:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package default-jdk
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be some lines before `E: Unable to parse package file` showing errors like this:

```
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/…
```

You need to

```
sudo rm -i /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt update
```

Do **not** forget the asterisk * in the first command!

Comment: Well sir I do have edited the question.Hope it clarifies the Question.

Comment: you need to remove all those files above and run `apt update`

Comment: I took the liberty to edit this in…